# Does using new String constructor is enough to ensure that two strings will have different references?

Tags: java

Today I was writing some simple junit test cases. One of then calls method that checks if string is equal to some other string stored before (and in that case string was supposed to have same value).

In working application that comparsion would be done after going from one jvm to other, so probably that two strings would have different reference. In test I was actually reusing same String. In pure theory, someone could change `equals()` to `==` and I wouldn't know that.

I've changed it so now second String in test is created with `new String(originalString)`. Is that enough to ensure that those two strings have different references?

Comment: normally, yes. without it, it will look for existing Objects with the same value, but the new keyword forces to add a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's enough. When you use the `new` keyword, it's guaranteed by Java language that the new object will be created which is distinct from any other objects created before. So you can be sure that java compiler or JIT compiler will not optimize this case.